# git fetch to different file

Tags: git

I am trying to download my website files to the `public_html` folder. But when I do `git init` it generates other files that I don't want to have in the root of my website.

I tried:

```
git init
git remote add origin [GIT_URL]
git fetch origin
```

But only got the Git files in the `public_html` folder (branches, hooks, info, etc.).

I also tried `git init --separate-git-dir=<git dir>` but also ended up with the same result. It created a file with the `gitdir: /path/to/git/folders` text.

Is there a way to create the Git repo in the parent folder of the `public_html` folder but the actual  files in a different folder location than the `public_html` folder?

Went through several Git tutorials, and they always show how to work from a newly created folder, not an existing folder (`public_html` in my case).

Comment: Git is not a deployment tool. You probably should find a real deployment tool and use that to deploy a particular commit from a repository in which you develop your files.

Comment: Can you suggest a deployment tool? 
Thanks.

Comment: you can potentially use the '--git-dir' qualifier to have your git directory completely out of picture. But maybe it is better to use a different deployment scheme, for example 'cp'/

Comment: I don't have any preferred one myself. StackOverflow isn't the right place to ask for such tools though: see instead superuser.com and similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***tl;dr***: Use `git clone [GIT_URL]`.

---

You've only fetched the remote repository to your new local one, but you haven't merged them into your local branch. Let's go through the commands.

- `git init`

Create an empty local repository in the current directory. It lives in `.git/`.

- `git remote add origin GIT_URL`

Attach `GIT_URL` as the remote repository named `origin`.

- `git fetch origin`

Fetch the remote repository `origin` and make remote tracking branches like `origin/master`.

At this point you've fetched the remote repository, but you're still left with just a `.git` directory. You need to merge `origin/master` into your local `master` branch.

- `git checkout master` if not already checked out
- `git merge origin/master`

Now your `master` matches the remote `master` and is checked out. Now you should see `.git` (the repository) and whatever is in your repository.

`git clone [GIT_URL]` does all of the above in one step. It initializes a new repository, adds GIT_URL as the origin remote, fetches origin, checks out `master`, and merges `origin/master` into `master`.

---

Now configure your web server to deny access to any `.git` directory.

Git is not a deployment tool, but you can get away with it for very small projects. A better simple solution would be to use a tool such as [`rsync`](https://rsync.samba.org/) to send your code (skipping `.git`) to the production server.

Comment: I like this answer, and I love the walk through make git more clear.  thanks

Comment: What about permissions on the public_html folder? would git leave those permissions untouched or is that why rsync is a better option. thanks

Comment: @SamArcos Your checked out files will have the permissions you committed them with. You'll want to make sure they're correct for a deployed web application. Git does not control the owner and group, that's up to how the user doing the checkout is set up. `rsync` is a better option because it's designed to sync directories. You can better control what files and directories get synched with what permissions. Ultimately you'll want to move to a full deployment system like [Heroku Pipeline](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pipelines) with staging servers, but rsync is fine for pushing HTML.